# ant copy filterset

Tags: ant, filter

Why does not my code below work? the filterset does not do a single replace in the newfile created

```
<copy file="${WT_HOME}/conf/auditing/configAudit.xml"
      tofile="${WT_HOME}/conf/auditing/configAudit1.xml" 
      overwrite="true">
    <filterset>
        <filter token="false" value="true"/>
    </filterset>
</copy>
```

Comment: Why does it not work? That depends on what you're trying to do - can you say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter you are using will replace `@false@` tokens with the value `true`.  It will not flip `false` to `true` which is what I am assuming you are trying to do.  If you want to replace occurrences of false with true you might want to look at using the [replace](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task.

Answer (score 6):

Late answer, but this page ranks high on Google's search results for "ant copy filter replace":

Try a [filterchain with tokenfilter/replacestring](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replacestring) instaed:

```
<copy file="${WT_HOME}/conf/auditing/configAudit.xml" tofile="${WT_HOME}/conf/auditing/configAudit1.xml" overwrite="true">
    <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
             <replacestring from="false" to="true"/>
        </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```